# Replace abbreviated month name with full name in a column of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']})
```

I want to convert all the abbreviated months in column `a` to their full name. I can do so using a `dict`

```
df_1.replace({'a' : { 'Jan' : "January", 'Feb' : "February", 'Mar' : "March" }})
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do so using the pandas datetime functionality and without having to type out the names of all the months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.to_datetime(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'], format='%b').month_name()})

          a
0   January
1  February
2     March
```

**--- or ---**

```
pd.to_datetime(df_1['a'], format='%b').dt.month_name()

0     January
1    February
2       March
```