# If I have a csv files with months written as jan, feb etc, can I convert them to full names January, etc? Using pandas or python?

Tags: pandas, csv, date, format

I have a csv file with a month column where the months are written in abbrevaiated form. e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar,

I want them to output at the full months for the purpose of a graph i.e. January, February, April etc

How do I format it using python or pandas?  I have tried

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].strftime('B%')
```

and various other things, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace abbreviated month name with full name in a column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186041/replace-abbreviated-month-name-with-full-name-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the names:

```
import calendar

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']})

mapper = dict(zip(calendar.month_abbr, calendar.month_name))

df['month_long'] = df['month'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
  month month_long
0   Jan    January
1   Feb   February
2   Mar      March
```

If a substring, use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex:

```
import calendar

mapper = dict(zip(calendar.month_abbr, calendar.month_name))

df['month_long'] = df['month'].str.replace(r'(%s)\b' % '|'.join(mapper),
                                           lambda m: mapper[m.group()],
                                           regex=True)
```

Example:

```
          month         month_long
0      Jan 2023       January 2023
1  Feb 1st 2023  February 1st 2023
2           Mar              March
```